# How can I do Stratified sampling with proportionate size

Tags: r, sampling

I have a dataset named by "Tree_all_exclusive" of 7607 rows and 39 column, which contains different information of tress such as age, height, name etc. I am able to create a sample of 1200 size with the below code, which looks picking trees randomly:

```
sam1<-sample_n(Tree_all_exclusive, size = 1200)
```

But I like to generate a proportionate stratified sample of 1200 trees which will pick the number of trees according to the proportion of the number of that specific type of tree.

To do this I am using below code:

```
sam3<-Tree_all_exclusive %>%
  group_by(TaxonNameFull)%>%
  summarise(total_numbers=n())%>%
  arrange(-total_numbers)%>%
  mutate(pro = total_numbers/7607)%>% #7607 total number of trees
  mutate(sz= pro*1200)%>% #1200 is number of sample
  mutate(siz=as.integer(sz)+1) #since some size is 0.01 so making it 1
sam3

s<-stratified(sam3, group="TaxonNameFull", sam3$siz)
```

But it is giving me the below error:

*Error in s_n(indt, group, size) : 'size' should be entered as a named vector.*

Would you please point me any direction to solve this issue?

Also if there is any other way to do the stratified sampling with proportionate number please guide me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: from which package is that stratified function? @Zerone

Answer (score 1):

How about using `sample_frac()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  tally()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>     cyl     n
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4    11
#> 2     6     7
#> 3     8    14

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  sample_frac(.5) %>% 
  tally()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>     cyl     n
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4     6
#> 2     6     4
#> 3     8     7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: If I may I ask, what have based on while selecting .5 proportion? @DaveArmstrong

Comment: Just something to demonstrate how the function works.